# Is there any way to set eclipse up for both Python and Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, eclipse

Can you set up eclipse for both Python and Ruby? I currently have it set up for java and python with PyDev. But when I try to install Aptana 3 plugin for ruby it won't let me saying that there is a conflicting dependency which I guess means I can have it set up for one or the other but not both? Anyone manage to set up eclipse for Java, Python and Ruby?

Comment: I actually ran into this same problem when I was using both Python and Ruby, I ended installing the standalone version of Aptana just for Ruby and JS stuff

Comment: have you tried the stand-alone version of aptana studio 3?  It's basically eclipse with the ruby and python plugins pre-installed.

Comment: Cheers. I think I might be just as easy to use Aptana. Eclipse has as a part of its dynamic lang toolkit ruby support but I'm having trouble setting that up as well (doesn't seem to want to find ruby interpreter) so Aptana it is.

Comment: Post the specific conflict error messages you're getting; usually those can be deciphered to determine what is conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to install Aptana plugins into an existing Eclipse installation usually doesn't work, in my experience. Instead, you could try installing the [Eclipse DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) which provides, among other things, a Ruby development environment.